# Use output of gitinfo2 package with datetime2 commands

Tags: errors, datetime2, gitinfo

The `gitinfo2` package provides the command `\gitAuthorDate` which returns the date of the current commit in ISO format, e.g., `2018-02-22`.

I would like to use this date with a different format within in my document, so I tried to use the `datetime2` package to save the output of `\gitAuthorDate` and reformat it.

Here is a minimal example (to be used in a git-versioned directory with the appropriate hooks installed as per the documentation of `gitinfo2`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[grumpy,mark]{gitinfo2}

\usepackage[calc]{datetime2}
\DTMsavedate{commitdate}{\gitAuthorDate}

\begin{document}

Hello world!

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, this gives me

```
Runaway argument?
\gitInf@authsdate \@dtm@endparsedate \cslet {@dtm@commitdate@year}{\@dtm@year \
ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \@dtm@parsedate was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.9
```

How can I fix this error, or is there another way to reformat the date provided by `\gitAuthorDate`?

**Edit**

As requested by Nicola, here is an excerpt of an interactive session to see how \gitAuthorDate expands

```
*\show\gitAuthorDate
...
> \gitAuthorDate=\long macro:
->\gitInf@authsdate .
*\makeatletter
*\show\gitInf@authsdate
> \gitInf@authsdate=macro:
->2018-02-22.
```

Comment: It's likely an expansion problem. `\DTMsavedate` performs a one-level expansion on the first token in the second argument, so it would work if, say, `\gitAuthorDate` is define as `2018-02-22` but not if it's defined in a more complicated manner. For those who don't have git, it would help to know exactly how `\gitAuthorDate` expands. Can you add `\show\gitAuthorDate` before `\DTMsavedate` and add the result.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot I have added the information you requested. If I replace the offending command by `\makeatletter\DTMsavedate{commitdate}{\gitInf@authsdate}\makeatother`, it works as expected. Are there any side-effects or is there a better solution? Otherwise, I am happy to keep this solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Turning comments into an answer.) `\DTMsavedate` performs a one-level expansion on the first token in the second argument, so it would work if, say, `\gitAuthorDate` is directly define as 2018-02-22 but not if it's defined in a more complicated manner. Given the expansion of `\gitAuthorDate` that you provided, you could use your proposed solution:

```
\makeatletter\DTMsavedate{commitdate}{\gitInf@authsdate}\makeatother
```

However, it's best not to use internal commands in case the package changes them in later versions. Instead, a more general solution is to ensure that the argument is fully expanded before being passed to `\DTMsavedate`:

```
\newcommand{\esavedate}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \edef\x{\noexpand\endgroup\noexpand\DTMsavedate{#1}{#2}}\x
}

\esavedate{commitdate}{\gitAuthorDate}
```